# browserSync + gulp

Tags: gulp

Estoy programando un proyecto en MEAN y apenas me encuentro con la parte de angular.

Quiero hacerlo todo desde cero para aprender sobre gulp y su funcionalidad así como de otras herramientas, sin embargo, me topé con el siguiente problema:

Cuando uso el `browser-sync` simplemente no funciona. Me abre el navegador como quiero y si me abre los archivos correctos, pero no actualiza el navegador cuando lo pido.

**Estructura de carpetas y archivos**

[image: archivos y carpetas]

**gulpfile.babel.js**

```
import gulp         from "gulp";
import browserify   from "browserify";
import source       from "vinyl-source-stream";
import htmlmin      from "gulp-htmlmin";
import streamify    from "gulp-streamify";
import uglify       from "gulp-uglify";
let browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

gulp.task("default", ["serve"]);

gulp.task("move-html", () => {
  return gulp.src("index.html")
    .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});

gulp.task("transpile", ["move-html"], () => {
  return browserify("src/app.js")
    .transform("babelify")
    .bundle()
    .on("error", function(error){
      console.error( "\nError: ", error.message, "\n");
      this.emit("end");
    }).pipe(source("bundle.js"))
    .pipe(streamify(uglify()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});

gulp.task("reload", ["transpile"], () => {
  browserSync.reload();
  done();
});

gulp.task("serve", () => {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "dist"
    }
  });
  gulp.watch("client/**/*", ["reload"]);
});
```

He revisado y seguido varios tutoriales pero ninguno me funciona, cuando ejecuto el comando del task `serve` (que aparece en mi gulpfile) me aparece la siguiente salida:

[image: gulp serve output]

Sin embargo, cuando hago actualizaciones en mis archivos, no se hace el reload del navegador.

Comment: `let browserSync` ¿que es let? Uso gulp a veces y nunca vi eso, ¿es un error o sirve para algo?

Comment: @blonfu es la nueva forma de crear variables dentro de un scope particular, revisa [es2015](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/) para que veas más información

Comment: ok, no lo sabía. Gracias por la info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya resolví el problema. Resulta que en mi función

`gulp.watch("client/**/*.js", ["reload"])`

Se está buscando una carpeta que no existe. Bastaba con quitar el  `client`del blob y listo.

Ahora mi `browsersync` funciona correctamente.